# Android LinearLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I tryning to get a LinearLayout in a ScrollView like this:

### [image]

The greenspace should be wrap_content and the red one should take the remaining space.

But this is my Result:

### [image]

This is my Code:

```
foreach(Ele el : elements) {}
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LayoutParams layout_parm = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(layout_parm);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
    tv.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1) );
    tv.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor((R.color.red)));
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    tv.setText("Name...");
    tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, getDP(5));
    layout.addView(tv);

    TextView iView = new TextView(getActivity());
    iView.setText("OTO");
    iView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    iView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor((R.color.green)));
    iView.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0) );
    layout.addView(iView);

    frg_layout.addView(layout); 
}
```

I am so confused! Maybe you can help me to find out my fail...
Thank you!

The Parent-ViewGroup:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frg_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: Switch from LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL to VERTICAL and add a Weight to layout of TextView. Thats it ;)

Comment: Or better and easer, create a layout file only with the linear layout and your two elements, use the inflater to load this resource. Then you can use the GUI desginer from AndroidStudio.

Comment: But VERTICAL means from top to bottom, i wish HORIZONTAL from left to right or isn't that fact right?
I try it out an i get the same result without space between rows...

Comment: what is the ViewGroup you're adding the LinearLayouts into (frg_layout)? Would be good to see what type it is, how it's defined, what are its layout params, etc.

Comment: When are r create design on android layout use xml very easy way to design

Comment: try use weight First item with android:layout_weight="2" the other with weight ="1"

Comment: @GilMoshayof It is a LinearLayout and this is in a scrollview...

Comment: Again, would like to see all its configuration - layout params, orientation, etc.

Comment: @GilMoshayof Post is edited

Comment: at which point during the life-cycle are you adding all these views into the LinearLayout?

Comment: After i download something from server...
in onResume i start a download and on finish, a interface is calling and then...

Comment: Could you post the full layout please? I only see the LInearLayout, and it's supposed to be inside a ScrollView, isn't it? The code you wrote (while it'd be a lot better if it were defined via XML) is supposed to do what you're expecting, which means the problem is elsewhere in your code. Please post as much relevant code as you can.

Answer (score 1):

you change the layout orientation

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
LayoutParams layout_parm = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(layout_parm);
```

uset this type in xml

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/frg_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView1"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview2"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
/>
</linearlayout>
```

Comment: But VERTICAL means from top to bottom, i wish HORIZONTAL from left to right or isn't that fact right? I try it out an i get the same result without space between rows...

Comment: Oh k change layoutParams match_parent like 250dp because match_parent use get full space on the layout

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mostly got it right, just need a few minor tweaks:

```
 for each(Ele el:elements){

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LayoutParams layout_parm = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layout_parm);

        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

        //adjust the last number here to make the first block wider or larger as you want
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor((R.color.red)));
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        tv.setText("Name...");
        tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, getDP(5));
        layout.addView(tv);

        TextView iView = new TextView(getActivity());
        iView.setText("OTO");
        iView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        iView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor((R.color.green)));

        //adjust your layout param to be a weight instead of wrap_content
        iView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        layout.addView(iView);

        frg_layout.addView(layout);
    }
```

See if that works! An alternative would be to build an xml layout which I think is generally cleaner, but programatically it should work roughly the same way.

Comment: Ok now the red box get 1/3 of space and the green 2/3...!
if i read your code correctly it should be the other way round?!

Comment: ? Wait a sec, no that's not right, 2 indicates that it should be larger! Now I'm confused.

Comment: This is incorrect. The requirement is that the green view wraps content, and red view takes the remaining space. Width 0 + Weight 1 for the Red view and Width wrap_content + Weight 0 for the Green view is the correct configuration. Something else is breaking the measurement.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what could be the problem, then. I usually do all this in XML so it's completely possible that I'm messing something up.

Comment: Yes i am confused too!!

@GilMoshayof you are right

Answer (score 0):

Using LayoutInflater with xml will bring the solutuion!

Thank you!